# how to import the existing test cases from excel file to kiwi tool

Tags: kiwi-tcms

i have a excel file which has 23 sheets and each has minimum 15 test cases. i need to import all the test cases into kiwitcms test management tool. We are exploring this tool for our project. There are almost more than 500+ test cases available for our application. Could anyone let us know is there any option for importing?

Answer (score 1):

See the following documentation
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import-export/index.html