# Can we write test cases in excel and upload into Kiwi tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I just started using Kiwi TCMS and i do not find an option to upload an excel into Kiwi TCMS.
I can only create one test case at a time which is consuming time for me. So i want to write the cases in an excel sheet and then upload it to Kiwi TCMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to import the existing test cases from excel file to kiwi tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798634/how-to-import-the-existing-test-cases-from-excel-file-to-kiwi-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is NO, you can't import Excel files directly, see the docs here:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import-export/index.html

Another user had started working on an import script mentioned at:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1104

If you decide to write something by youself please be a good open source citizen and contribute it back to our api-scripts repository (all mentioned in the docs).

To speed up writing process you can use the "Clone" functionality when writing test cases or parse/import from existing sources using the API.